# packaging java files

Tags: java, inheritance, packaging, abstract

I'm trying to package a set of java files that compile/run just fine before packaging. After adding 
    package 
in the first line I'm getting the following error!

```
cannot find symbol 
symbol: class Person
```

Here is a simplified code snippet that result in the same error:
package people;

-Person.java

```
package people;
abstract public class Person
{
// some code
}
```

-Female.java

```
package people;
public class Female extends Person
{   
Female(){}
    // some code
}
```

Comment: make sure the Person class is compiled.

Comment: what is the contents of your jar?

Comment: Do you really have a folder called 'people' where the classes were placed

Answer (score 1):

When you say "packaging", do you mean "after adding the `package` declaration" in your source code ?

If so, I think you omitted that a java package needs to reflect the actual directory where your source files reside. In order for `package people;` to work, you need to create a directory named `people` and place your source files there.

As I assume you're using `javac`, if you compile both files at once, with `javac *.java` this should work fine (even if you don't have the files residing in the proper directory). But if you want to compile them separately, you need to run `javac` from the parent directory of `people`.

```
$ mkdir people
$ mv Person.java Female.java people/
$ javac people/Person.java
$ javac people/Female.java
```

Answer (score 1):

"cant find symbol" usually signifies that the compiler cannot find an identifier that you are trying to use. Here it looks like it cannot find the class Person. I assume this error is being thrown in the class Female.

How are you compiling the source files? Do you use an IDE like Eclipse or are you compiling it through the command line? If you are using an IDE it would help you better in identifying the problem.

When compiling through the command line you should make sure you compile Person before the class Female. And since the class files are inside a package you should compile the files from the root of your source

Example - 
Person.java and Female.java are inside the package "pack", this is how I would compile

```
D:\Applications\eclipse\eclipse-workspace\Test\src>javac pack\*.java
D:\Applications\eclipse\eclipse-workspace\Test\src>
```